# How do you share data between apps without one app being the host?

Tags: android

Is there any shared datastore API solution on Android that works for many:many access?

**Scenario**:

- 10+ Apps, any subset of which can be installed on the device.
- Device is generally offline, so can't rely on syncing with a server

**Desired Outcome**:

- Each app needs to read/write some basic string key/value pairs (such as login keys and other account data) so that the user sees their data as the same in all apps.
- On iOS we use the Keychain API and whitelist each of the bundle ids of our apps.

**Failed Solutions?**

- `SharedPreferences` with `Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE` and using android:sharedUserId

  - Deprecated in API v17
- `ContentProvider`: As I understand it, this is generally used in a server->client architecture where you know one app will be the host of the data and others will consume it. In our scenario, any subset of our apps will be installed.

**Solution?**

- The best solution I can come up with is making each app a `ContentProvider` and a `BroadcastReceiver`. On modifications to the data, we would have to broadcast to all installed apps so their data is up to date (in case the app with the latest data is deleted). On load of each app, we would query all other apps for their data, and if any have a timestamp greater than ours, we can override our data.

  - This seems like a very heavyweight approach to something that seems like it should be supported through the Android API.
- Another solution would be to write an encrypted file to a shared location.

  - The downside to this is we would need to request file write permissions, and our apps do not need this already. We would like to avoid that if possible.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "Is there any shared datastore API solution on Android that works for many:many access?" -- not really, as you have defined the problem. "This seems like a very heavyweight approach to something that seems like it should be supported through the Android API" -- outside of device manufacturers, very few developers create a suite of independent apps as you are.